# Creating and changing existent Methods for Dart classes

Tags: dart

I'm trying to program with Dart on Visual Studio Code and need to understand the Syntax of Dart a bit more to be able to code what is needed.

**These are the classes I have coded:**

1. Book (defines book title, isbn, price and availability)

```
class Book {
    // properties
    late String _title;
    late int _isbn;
    late double _price;
    bool _isAvailable;
....
}
```

2. BookCatalog (imports prior class and defines current list of books + methods to add new books)

```
class BookCatalog{

  // no arrays, everything is a list
  List<Book> _books = [];
...
}
```

3. Main (imports prior classes and executes wanted input)

**What I want to change:**

1. improve addBook Method within BookCatalog Class, to not add a new Book, if it has the same ISBN as a already existing one, which it currently does. (Potentially give out message stating 'false' if user tries to add Book with same ISBN)

```
// adds a book to the store
void addBook(book) {
    _books.add(book);
  }
```

2. improve printBookCatalog Method within BookCatalog Class, to only print available Books and not all Books added to the Store.

```
 // Print books contained in the catalog
  void printBookCatalog() {
    print("List of Books:");
    for (var book in _books) {
      print(book);
    }
  }
```

3. improve getBook Method within BookCatalog Class, to *actually* get the book by its ID, as it's not working right now.

```
// Get a book by id
  Book getBook(int place) => _books[place];
```

4. improve calculateAvgPrice Method within BookCatalog Class, to calculate the average price of Books, it's not working correctly as of now

```
// NEW, calculates average price of books
  Book calculateAvgPrice(double price) {
    for(var book in _books) {
      sum += book.Price;
    }
    return sum / _books.length;
  }
```

5. create a new Method within BookCatalog Class to delete Books from the Catalog

answer could be, but I'm not sure :

```
// deletes book from the catalog
   void deleteBook(book) {
    _books.remove(book);
  }
```

Any help, explanations, examples or external sources to read up on Dart would be appreciated!

(Especially examples for my specific cases)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest going through [Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) first.

(Side note: ISBN has leading zero and hyphen, so it's better to use a `String` for it instead of `int`)

In your `BookCatalog` class, you could use a `Map` instead of a `List`:

```dart
class BookCatalog {
  Map<String, Book> _books = {}; // Map from ISBN to Book
  // ...
}
```

1. Here I'm assuming that both classes are in the same file, otherwise accessing private members wouldn't work, so you'd have to have public getters available.

```dart
/// Adds a book to the store only if the ISBN does NOT exist.
bool addBook(Book book) {
  if (_books.containsKey(book._isbn)) {
    return false;
  }
  _books[book._isbn] = book;
  return true;
}
```

2. Missing the `if` conditional.

```dart
void printBookCatalog() {
  print("List of Books:");
  for (final book in _books.values) {
    if (book._isAvailable) {
      print(book);
    }
  }
}
```

3. Assuming that by `id` you mean, its ISBN. It returns a nullable `Book?` because the isbn might not exist in the catalog.

```dart
// Get a book by id
Book? getBook(String isbn) => _books[isbn];
```

4. The function has a return type of `double` not a `Book` as it's the average price. You also don't need to provide any argument to this function. And you need to define the sum variable first before using it!

```dart
double calculateAvgPrice() {
  var sum = 0.0;
  for (final book in _books.values) {
    sum += book._price;
  }
  return sum / _books.length;
}
```

5. Assuming that you want to remove books by their ISBN:

```dart
bool removeBook(String isbn) {
  return _books.remove(isbn) != null;
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your elaborate answer, But for my class I'm not allowed to use a map but have to make do with a list for now when it comes to creating the BookCatalog Class, so most of your answers use actions I'm not allowed to use yet. I'll definitely look into the Link you have sent me!